# computing cost in optimum way in high dimensional space

Tags: visual-c++-6

how to find contours of equal function value on a high dimensional space in optimal way provided function values is monotonically non-decreasing along all dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function is monotonic in both X and Y this becomes straight forward to find the contour. Lets find the solutions of f(x,y)-K = 0.

Step 1. Calculate the function at the four corners. This will tell you which edges the contour intersects.

Step 2. Pick one of the edges with a solution. Use a subdivision algorithm to find a solution on this edge. First find the mid-point and calculate the value there. This splits the edge in two, exactly one will have sign change, pick that edge and repeat. This process will give the unique solution on the edge.

Step 3. Starting at the end point use a zero following technique. We start with a square with a solution on one edge, and known values at two corners. Evaluate the function at the other two corners. Compare signs and find the other edge with a solution on it. Get the adjacent square and repeat.

This will follow the curve until we reach the other solution on the boundary. Being monotonic means there are no tricky cases to deal with.

---

More on step 3: We have a rectangle with two know points

```
+ ____ -
|      |
|      |
? ____ ?
```

there are three possibilities

```
+ ____ -
|      |
|      |    take the right hand side
+ ____ +

+ ____ -
|      |    take the bottom side
|      |
+ ____ -

+ ____ -
|      |
|      |    take the left hand side
- ____ -
```

One option can't occur as the function is monotonic

```
+ ____ -
|      |     impossible
|      |   
- ____ +
```

Comment: Yes I mean immediate squares adjacent to the one we are currently at. Repeating this process will follow the curves one square at a time. You can show this process will either get back to the starting point or hit the boundary. 

If you need a set of contour lines, simply repeat with different values of K. You can store calculated values in some data structure to save having to recalculate the function.

Comment: Lack of monotonicity complicates things greatly. The impossible case above can now occur so you can get crossing points on the contour. Worse you can get small closed loops which do not cross the boundary.

Do you know anything about the bumps? If you can get some bound on the size of a bump then you may be able to exclude some parts of the domain. If say the function does not change by more that `a` over the size of a square that means square where one corner is greater than `2a` can not contain the contour.

Comment: Thanks Salix alba. I dont have any specific bounds on the bumps. But the monotonicity is not uniform at some locations in the space. I can agree with certain amount of error in contour but the number of points examined needs to be the least.

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate the function at four corners of a square, the four values will tell you if the square is crossed by the iso-K curve.

Now subdivide the square in four sub-squares and check the function values at the new corners (this costs 5 function evaluations). Thanks to the monotonicity property, you are ensured that at least one of the squares can be discarded.

If you continue this process recursively, the number of points is reduced by at least 25% on every stage, and 32 stages will suffice to reduce from 10000 to 1 (0.75^32 = 0.000100...), requiring in total no more than 32 x 5 = 160 function evaluations.